# How do you link images in a data-attribute when using webpack?

Tags: url, webpack, vue.js, custom-data-attribute

I'm using a simple carousel plugin in a Vue.js SPA compiled by webpack.  For the carousel, the images are loaded via a data attribute

`<div class="carousel-cell" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="../../assets/images/photos/projeKt-01.jpg"></div>`

Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work. After verifying the paths were indeed correct, I realized the problem is that webpack doesn't seem to be resolving the paths on compile.  I was able to test this by linking to some off-site images in the carousel data-attributes and they loaded just fine.

I suspect the local images are failing to render because webpack is choking on resolving the (data-) urls.  The "url in a data-attribute" seems like a semi-common pattern one might run into, so I'm hoping there's a simple solution I've overlooked.

Here's my webpack.base.conf.js file (this is generated from the typical Vue CLI setup - nothing special):

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: "pre",
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480492/how-to-get-image-that-is-within-a-data-attrbute-with-webpack-2 also can you post your webpack config.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, I updated with the webpack config file.  I'll look over that link!