# handle data attributes with webpack and vuejs

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, src, custom-data-attribute

I use the **vue cli with webpack** and I'm absolutely fine with it. But now I have a little problem!

I want that the **path** in the `data` attributes from the `<object>` tags are also compiled like the `src` attributes from the `<img>` tags

**for example:**

If I do something like this

`<img src="../path/to/file.svg" alt="">`

webpack compiled the path to

`<img src="/dist/path/to/file.svg" alt="">`

but when I do something like this:

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../path/to/file.svg">fallback</object>`

it doesn't work :(

Comment: You'll need to add a new loader rule in your webpack config such as html-loader and configure to scrape that attribute. Not behind computer so unable to provide syntax.

Comment: I try it with the html-loader. Maybe I do a mistake with the configuration, but I get an error from the babel-loader. I think the babel-loader do something with the `data` attribute as well.

If I try the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480492/how-to-get-image-that-is-within-a-data-attrbute-with-webpack-2) I only get a blank page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `require()` helper

Example:

```
<object :data="require(`../path/to/file-${if-you-need-to-pass-a-variable-here}.svg`)" type="image/svg+xml" >fallback</object>
```

---

```
<img :src="require(`../path/to/file-${if-you-need-to-pass-a-variable-here}.svg`)" alt="">
```